# Lock the particular cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how to lock the individual cell in excel. For example if I share a excel to my colleague, they can modify anything in that excel but they should not have access to modify the particular cell (A7) alone. Please someone assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1- Unprotect all the cells
   Select all the cells,
   Right-click ---> Format Cells ---> Protection Tab: Uncheck Locked

2- Protect your particular Cell (i.e. A7)
   Select your cell A7
   Right-click ---> Format Cells ---> Protection Tab: Check Locked
   Do the same for all cells or ranges you want to protect.

3- Protect the Worksheet
   Right-click the sheet's Tab, click "Protect Sheet..."
   Select the options you want. 'Basically, you want default (first 2 options)
   Enter a password and click OK
```

Whenever you want to unprotect the sheet, just do the inverse of step 3:

```
Right-click the sheet's Tab, click "Unprotect Sheet..."
Enter your password and click OK
```

A final note, remember that locking cells has **no effect** until the sheet is protected.

Comment: Awesome. Really great. and that too your way of explanation.

Comment: OOPS sorry. I didn't know before you says. I have checked the tick and it changed into green. Thank You

Comment: And I have one more doubt regarding hyperlink in excel. Shall I ask

Comment: @suresh You are welcome! of course you can ask another question, there's no limit on SO. :)

Comment: Actually I need to hyperlink a word document in excel. The file is in my folder. How can I hyperlink it and need to share the file.

Comment: Write this in the Excel cell: `=HYPERLINK("C:\myFolder\myWordDoc.docx")` @suresh

Comment: sorry I cant understand. Could you please tell how to attach the file here. I will attach the file and will explain you clearly. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @suresh By the site's rule that should be subject of a new question, dont hesitate to ask more questions, and remember to add as much detail as possible to describe the problem :)